# What does the format '(a,2(2x,3i4))' mean?

Tags: fortran, format, output

I am working with some code in Fortran where the format of writing out to some file is `'(a,2(2x,3i4))'`.

How do you break each part of this down to understand what it means?

Comment: This is quite basic and should take just a few minutes with any Format string tutorial or manual. Be aware that the `write` statement you used in the title was different and incorrect. I just removed it and used the version from your question body. But you should normally show the **full** `write` statement, including the output list (the list of variables or expressions to be written). I assume it was one string and six integer numbers.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

- a = character string of the length in the value
- 2( = group repeat of what's in the parentheses two times
- 2x = skip two columns
- 3i4 = 4-digit integer, left padded with blanks if needed, repeated three times